# How to add an automatic slider function to my jquery slider?

Tags: jquery

I have added a new template to my blogger and it has a slider  with some image related to the blog and the problem is " the slider only runs when I click the next button or previous button " and I need to slide it automatically someone help me so,I would have thankful to them..

The code is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
            jQuery(function() {
              var Page = (function() {
                var $navArrows = jQuery( &#39;#nav-arrows&#39; ).hide(),
                                        //$shadow = jQuery( &#39;#shadow&#39; ).hide(),
                                        slicebox = jQuery( &#39;#sb-slider&#39; ).slicebox( {
                                        onReady : function() {
                  $navArrows.show();
                  //$shadow.show();
                },
                  orientation : &#39;r&#39;,
                  cuboidsRandom : true,
                    easing : &#39;ease&#39;
              } ),
                  init = function() {
                    initEvents();
                  },
                  initEvents = function() {
                    // add navigation events
                    $navArrows.children( &#39;:first&#39; ).on( &#39;click&#39;, function() {
                                        slicebox.next();
                    return false;
                  } );
              $navArrows.children( &#39;:last&#39; ).on( &#39;click&#39;, function() {
                                  slicebox.previous();
              return false;
            } );
            };
            return { init : init };
            })();
            Page.init();
            });
          </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very hard to decipher, but try something like this:

```
myInt = setInterval( $('.next').click(), 5000 );
```

**Source(s)**

[MDN - setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)
[jQuery API - .click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)